# How to get power by knowing the number and result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, power-series

**How to get  power by knowing the number and result.**

***For Example***

$$2^n = 8$$

how can i return the power $n$ by knowing number $2$ and result $8$

or

$$4^n = 1024$$

how can i return the power 'n' by knowing number $4$ and result $1024$

Is there any formula

> Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is what the [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is for.  If $a^b=c, b=\log_a c$  There are many rules for manipulating logarithms.  In your examples, $\log_2 8=3, \log_4 1024=5$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the number (in your case 8), repeatedly (in fact, n number of times) by the base (which is 2).

Comment: Thanks....................+1

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

$$2^n = 8$$

We can simply rewrite 8 as a power of $2$:

$$2^n=2^3$$

As the bases are the same, we can drop the $2$ on both sides leaving us with:

$$\boxed{n=3}$$

The same can be applied in the case of $4^n = 1024$ as we are again dealing with nice numbers.

$$4^n=1024\\4^n=4^5\\\boxed{n=5}$$